# Как сделать, чтобы эта svg иконка стала белой?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

[image]

У меня есть иконка svg, я не знаю как её вставить, у я вот так прописал `

```
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" iewBox="0 0 50 50">
                 <g>
                    <path id="clock_blog" d="images/clock-blog.svg" />
                 </g>
              </svg>-->``
```

Но я не знаю как редактировать размер, что написать. **,  Помогите пожалуйста **

Comment: Мне надо как-то получить svg картинку в d

Comment: Уважаемый а Вы не хотите воспользоваться вот этой штукой ? http://fontawesome.ru/icon/clock-o/

Comment: hover там делать просто i.fa.fa-clock:hover и всё

Comment: Есть сайт с милионым выбором иконок, и там можно редактировать перед тем как скачать.  https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/clock_63355#term=clock&page=1&position=18

Comment: А так не работает если указать на path в css path{fill: orange;} ?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как-то так можно извлечь путь и добавить в свою `svg`

```js
let downloadedSvgAsText = `<svg><path d="M10,10 l10,-10 l10,10 l10,-10"></svg>`
let tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = downloadedSvgAsText;
let d = tmp.querySelector('path').getAttribute('d');
document.querySelector('#clock_blog').setAttributeNS(null, 'd', d);
console.log(d);
```

```css
body{
background-color:black
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
   <g>
      <path fill="white" id="clock_blog" d=""/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

`downloadedSvgAsText` скачать либо через `xmlhttprequest` либо `fetch`, а еще лучше использовать какой нибудь `webpack` и вставлять эти картинки еще при сборке